# How to close _ArrayDisplay() window?

Tags: window, autoit

How to close `_ArrayDisplay()`'s window using AutoIt script itself? I tried `WinClose()`:

```
_ArrayDisplay($aarray,"sometitle")
; do some stuff
Winclose("sometitle")  
Sleep(1000)
_ArrayDisplay($barray,"anothertitle")
```

but fails (previous window doesn't get closed and next window doesn't appear). So I tried `WinKill()`:

```
_ArrayDisplay($aarray,"sometitle")
; do some stuff
Winkill("sometitle")  
Sleep(1000)
_ArrayDisplay($barray,"anothertitle")
```

then previous window is closed, but the next window never appears. It seems `Winkill()` killed *all* `_ArrayDisplay()` instances. Other attempts :

```
_ArrayDisplay($aarray,"sometitle")
; do some stuff
While WinExists("sometitle")
    Winclose("sometitle") 
    Sleep(100)
WEnd
Sleep(1000)
_ArrayDisplay($barray,"anothertitle")
```

And:

```
_Arraydisplay($aarray,"sometitle")
; do some stuff
WinActivate("sometitle")
While WinExists("sometitle")
    Send("!{F4}"      
    Sleep(100)
WEnd
Sleep(1000)
_Arraydisplay($barray,"anothertitle")
```

I also tried `Send()` using `"!{F4}"` and `"{ALTDOWN}{SPACE DOWN}c{ALTUP}{SPACE UP}"`. All fail to close previous `_ArrayDisplay()` window. How to make this work?

Comment: neither `winclose` nor `winkill` should be able to do anything, because they are not executed before `_Arraydisplay` is closed.

Comment: `_ArrayDisplay` (as any other command) is executed to it's end, before the next command is getting executed. That's why your approach can't work: no matter, what command you put after `_ArrayDisplay` it will only start, when `_ArrayDisplay` is finished (the window gets closed). Michaels solution does work, because `AdlibRegister` does interrupt the loop in  `_ArrayDisplay` and "steal it it's window". (Remembers me of an old BASIC command `Every <n> GOSUB`).

Comment: Detailed description for this question slipped its mind because of my poor English. In fact strictly speaking, where I try to close previous arraydisplay window on my script is not the line after _arraydisplay() command in the same process.  Target Arraydisplay window is opened at the end of regular process which is setting the task queue table and starting the batch task. And the action of closing target window is in a monitoring process which is executed every 30 seconds by external trigger.

Comment: This is why I didn't understand your comment, "because they are not executed before _Arraydisplay is closed". It's my fault because I didn't give you description well.
Btw, monitoring process works well, no matter whether _ArrayDisplay window opened or not, except for closing that window. Winclose() no effect, winkill() kills that window together with next array window, and taskkill command with Run() for closing window with the title kills autoit program which opens that window. But Adlibregister() closes that window successfully. This is why I was wondering about it. Thank you:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <array.au3>

Global $aarray[1]
Global $barray[1]

AdlibRegister('_Closer')

_Arraydisplay($aarray, 'sometitle')
Sleep(1000)
_Arraydisplay($barray, 'anothertitle')

Func _Closer()
    If WinExists('sometitle') Then
        WinClose('sometitle')
        AdlibUnRegister('_Closer')
    EndIf
EndFunc
```

_ArrayDisplay is a Gui which uses a message loop. The script remains in
the loop until an event allows an exit from the loop.

One concept of doing an action while looping is to register a function
using [AdlibRegister](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/AdlibRegister.htm). The _Closer function registered above will be
called every 250 milliseconds until [AdlibUnRegister](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/AdlibUnRegister.htm) can stop the function
from being called.

Comment: But, what if you try to close the previous window by mouse click  before adlib()'s auto closing action? Unfortunately it seems the previous window persist opened to configured sleep time and adlib() function prevents next one opening and kills it as soon as it appears. I tried insert msgbox() between two arraydisplay(), but no effect. It kills exactly the next arraydisplay window..;;;

Comment: For your reference, leave test code here..   #1) AdlibRegister('_Closer')
  #2) _Arraydisplay($aarray, 'sometitle')
  #3) MsgBox(0,"","")
  #4) Sleep(1000)
  #5) _Arraydisplay($barray, 'anothertitle')
  #6) Func _Closer()
  #7) Sleep(10000)
  #8)   If WinExists('sometitle') Then
  #9)        WinClose('sometitle')
  #10)        AdlibUnRegister('_Closer')
  #11)    EndIf
  #12) EndFunc

Answer (score 0):

Now I have tried to modify "array.au3" a little bit in the section of the function _Arraydisplay() for inserting a timeout option(parameter), and feels like quite successful..

I added 3 lines in _Arraydisplay() and those are as follows..
At first, I added timeout option parameter($TimeOut=0) at the end of the function declaration section.

```
Func _ArrayDisplay(Const ByRef $aArray, $sTitle = Default, $sArrayRange = Default, $iFlags = Default, $vUser_Separator = Default, $sHeader = Default, $iMax_ColWidth = Default, $iAlt_Color = Default, $hUser_Function = Default, $TimeOut = 0)
```

And next, I inserted a line initiating timer in the function's starting point.

```
If $TimeOut > 0 Then Local $_Start = TimerInit()
```

And lastly, inserted a line into the while-loop for escaping while-loop when timer value reached $TimeOut(sec unit).

```
If $TimeOut > 0 And TimerDiff($_Start)/1000 >= $TimeOut Then ExitLoop
```

That's all.. And it works quite well..

For calling that function with timeout option( 7 seconds),

```
Arraydisplay($aarray, 'sometitle', 7)
; do some stuff
Sleep(1000)
Arraydisplay($barray, 'anothertitle')

Func Arraydisplay(Const ByRef $aArray, $sTitle="", $TimeOut = 0)
_Arraydisplay($aArray, $sTitle, Default,Default,Default,Default,Default,Default,Default,$TimeOut)
EndFunc
```

Of course, this is not a solution for closing arraydisplay window, but I think it will be some help for it, so I leave this answer. Thank you:-)